# Script unable to differ between subdirectories and files

Tags: bash, printing, directory

I am writing a bash script to print all the files in a directory. If there is a subdirectory, then expand it and print all the file in it also. This is a recursive process I have handled with the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash

#lsall -> list all the file in a directory and sub directory

print_dir_content(){
        echo -e "\nIn $1: (DIRECTORY)\n"
        for i in `ls $1`; do
                if ! [ -d $i ]; then
                        echo -e "F\t$i"
                else
                        print_dir_content $i
                fi
        done
}

if [ $# -lt 1 ]; then
       echo "Usage: $0 [DIR]"
       exit
else
        DIR="$1"
fi

if ! [ -d $DIR ]; then
        echo "Usage: $0 [DIR]"
        exit
fi

echo -e "\nIn $DIR:\n"
for i in `ls $DIR`; do
        echo "$i"
        if [ -d $i ]; then
                print_dir_content $i
        else
                echo -e "F\t$i"
        fi
done
```

The script runs with no errors though, subdirectories are seen as files and the recursive function cannot print the content of the inner directory. Since I am new to bash but not to programming, is this some language problem that I am facing, or it's a logical one? Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Why you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). If you want to list all files in and below the directory $DIR, try `find $DIR -type f -print`. If you want to call `foo` on all files in and below the directory $DIR, try `find $DIR -type f -exec foo {} \;`. Generally speaking, check [`man find`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find) to save yourself a *lot* of scripting headaches.

Comment: Are you re-inventing the wheel? Wouldn't a `find "$DIR" -type f` do exactly what you need?

Comment: If you do what the [tag:bash] tag you used instructs, "For shell scripts with syntax or other errors, please check them at https://shellcheck.net before posting them here." it'll tell you about issues with your script.

Comment: In general it's best to avoid negatives when possible since negative logic is a bit harder to understand than positive logic and can lead to the dreaded double negatives. In the function `print_dir_content` the condition under which we reach the line `echo -e "F\t$i"` is "it is true that $i is **not** a directory" (negative) and then we reach `print_dir_content "$i"` when "it is **not** true that $i is **not** a directory" (double negative). Flip it to get rid of the negation (`!`) and then it becomes clearer/simpler as `if [ -d "$i" ]; then print_dir_content "$i"; else echo -e "F\t$i"; fi`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code does not do `cd` but the `ls` output is a relative path.
A non-existent file cannot be a directory so the file branch will be taken. (Unless the top-level has a directory with the same name, in which case you'll end up in an infinite loop.)

```
#!/bin/bash

print_dir_content()(
    echo -e "\nIn $1: (DIRECTORY)\n"
    cd "$1" || exit
    for i in *; do
        if [ -d "$i" ]; then
            print_dir_content "$i"
        else
            echo -e "F\t$i"
        fi
    done
)

dir=$1
if ! [ -d "$dir" ]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 [DIR]"
    exit
fi

print_dir_content "$dir"
```

- parsing `ls` output is considered bad practice
- your final loop is just the recursive function (you can parameterise if you want to retain the different message)
- `(`...`)` spawns a subshell; alternatively you can `cd ..` at the end of the function (bash also has `pushd`/`popd`)

  - I just abort the function if `cd` failed; you could print a message or do other handling
- variable use should usually be quoted to avoid word-splitting
- ALLCAPS variable names are reserved for use by the shell
- zero-length names cannot exist so you can simplify the sanity checks
- you'll need slightly more complicated code if you want to list files/directories whose names begin with `.`

---

I'm assuming this is for learning; `find` or `ls -R` already allow recursive listing.

Comment: this code will incorrectly print `F *` if a subdirectory is empty. one way to fix is to set `shopt -s nullglob`

Answer (score 0):

Don't parse output from `ls` since it is error-prone.

And how about `find`?

```
find . -type f -mindepth 1
```

This should find all `f`ile under current folder.

Can change folder from `.` to another name based on your need.